# Factory Reset Dual Boot System

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows, bootloader

Dell Laptop / EUFI Bios / Dual-Boot / Orig OS Win8 Updated to Win 10 / Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS  -
Using a partion tool I allocated space from the Windows data drive to install Ubuntu and let the default grub set up the bootloader.  While doing this, I have now lost access to the Factory Reset / Recovery partion on the Harddrive. Any Suggestions on restoring to oriinal configuration?
I tried to restore/repair the Windows Bootloader using "bootrec /fixmbr" & "bootrec /fixboot" with no success, then "boot-rpeair" to back to square one.

Boot Info Summary is available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nGfK5w5mWT/

Comment: It depends on how old your laptop is. On some newer models, you can restore the original Windows from a setting in the bios if you overwrote the recovery partition in the HD. I don't think it will keep the Ubuntu OS though so you may have to re-install it and fix the boot.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows Recovery Environment partition (WinRE) is deleted, there is no good safe way to recover it immediately. However, it will be automatically recreated with a major windows update. I recommend you wait a bit until the Windows 10 October update (20H2) that will be coming out this month comes out and update then. Your partition will be recreated then.

Answer (score 0):

The WinRE partition is still intact and there is no Bios option to restore Windows.  I know if I reset that I will loose Ubuntu but I intend to reinstall.
I will look into The Windows October update (20H2).
Thanks